# Passing arguments to a form obtained by 'getattr()'

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

I'm creating a view which loads differents forms according to an argument given using the getattr() function:

```
 form = getattr(forms, service.form)
```

but in the form I need my username to filter my files, so I have this:

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    filename = forms.MultipleChoiceField(widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple)
    K = forms.CharField(label='K', max_length=1)
    fullOut = forms.CharField(label='fullOut', max_length=1)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.user = kwargs.pop('user', None)
        self.fields['filename'].queryset = userFile.objects.filter(self.user)
```

The problem is that I don't know how to pass the 'request.user' in my getattr() funtion. I know that if it was static it should be something like:

```
form = MyForm(user=request.user)
```

But I have tried somethings like:

```
form = getattr(forms, service.form, user=request.user)
```

And it doesn't work.I'm trying this but any idea of how list user files in a form will be welcomed. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: But my forms is my forms.py defined on my app (The content is in the question). Then in my views.py I have the import 'from scripts import forms' and my view with the getattr(forms, formname) function.

Comment: `MyForm = getattr(forms, 'MyForm')` will return the exact same class as `from scripts.forms import MyForm`. If instantiating that form is giving an error, then please post the traceback.

Comment: Yes. If you check the code of the form it expects an 'user' argument in __init__ right? So if I call the form like: form = MyForm(user=request.user) it works, but if I do it without passing the user argument it throws me: TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'user'

Comment: I think you are getting the error messages mixed up as well, you would get `unexpected keyword argument 'user` when you *do* pass `user`, not when you do not pass it. See my updated answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't have anything to do with you using getattr, the problem is in your `__init__` method. You need to pop `user` **before** calling `super()`.

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.user = kwargs.pop('user', None)
    super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

You should instantiate the form as you usually do:

```
form = MyForm(user=request.user)
```

It doesn't matter whether `MyForm` is declared in the same module:

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
   my_field = forms.CharField()

form = MyForm(user=request.user)
```

or if you get the form class dynamically using `getattr`

```
 MyForm = getattr(forms, service.form)
 form = MyForm(user=request.user)
```

Comment: yes, sorry, getattr returns the form class. The problem is that if you do your last example, it fails in the first line with a '__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'user'' because in the first call I'm not passing the 'user' argument to init.

Comment: My last example would throw an error on the second line when you instantiate the form, not the first. See my updated answer, I think the problem is in your `__init__` method.